# Using wpf form inside winforms. Won't build, no errors

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, embedding

I have a WPF application, very simple, just to test this approach. I create a dll using the class library template.

I am embedding it inside a test winforms app, with:

```
namespace embedder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WPFUserControl.UserControl1 control = new WPFUserControl.UserControl1();
            elementHost1.Child = control;
        }
    }
}
```

In this test application, it works great. However, when I try to add it to my existing application, in exactly the same way, (new form, same code as above, add the dll as a reference)

This time, the build fails. No errors, no intelsense, it just says 'Build Failed'

Due to no errors, i am completely stuck. Is there anything that i can try to get this working? Why would it build in one app, and not another?

(I have tried the dll as 32, and 64, release and debug).

Comment: what about .net versions? Is the project using older .net than the .dll ?

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. (for others as knowledge-less as me, .Net version is checked/changed, like this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx